# Sound is using exclusively max volume or mute. When plugging in audio in headphone jack popping noises in the speaker. What is the problem?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm using an Asus Zenbook with Intel integrated audio. The audio volume is always maxed out and the only way to lower it is to use mute. When I plug a sound cable into the audio output all I can hear is popping noises. I think it must be some driver problem because when I use the computer with Windows 10 the audio works. Also there is no problem when using bluetooth headphones. How can I install the right drivers or configure pulseaudio etc. to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a ZenBook and had the same problem.

By running `alsamixer` in the terminal, I noticed that my actual sound volume was depending on the **PCM value**, not the Master value. You can use the arrow keys on your keyboard to change the values in the mixer while playing music or something. If the situation is the same for you, this should be your solution:

Open the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and run:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

Use the arrow keys on the keyboard to navigate down to this section:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

...and add these lines **before** it:

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

Use CTRL+X to exit, say yes to save the changes and ENTER without changing the file name.

With the AlsaMixer, you can set the master value to 0, reboot your computer, and the volume keys and other controls should work fine now.